API для удобной работы с Яндекс.Таблицами
Есть ли Python API для удобной работы с Яндекс.Таблицами, чтобы была возможность изменять документ, не скачивая его?
Появилась идея вносить изменения в яндекс.таблицу при помощи телеграм-бота. Раньше решал подобную задачку, но там все было достаточно просто, и файл просто скачивался, изменялся, а затем вновь загружался на диск. А теперь хотелось бы изменять данные в таблице "на лету". Всё, что нашёл - это аналоги у Google, их API - google sheets, работает так, как мне нужно. На python даже оболочка для этого API есть - pydrive.
Может кто-то решал схожую задачу? Или просто знает ответ? :)

насколько мне известно, Яндекс в принципе не позволяет редактировать "на лету".

забей, "убийца гугл таблиц" от яндекса - это то еще г...По факту это даже не их софт, а просто какой то огрызок R7 офиса, не имеющий на борту даже трети полезных функций, имеющихся у гугла. Я уже молчу про API
